# Select object with max attribute in list of objects

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of 'nodes' and I'm trying to select the node that has the max value from that list. The following code achieves this, but I think it could be done in a much more elegant way. Is there a nice way to do this with list comprehensions that I'm missing? Thanks in advance!

Example code:

```
maxVal = 0
for node in self.nodes:
    if node.val > maxVal:
        maxVal = node.val
        self.maxValNode = node
self.maxVal = self.maxValNode.val
```

Comment: `list comprehension` is used when your output is list. In this case you want max value of node so you can not use it here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `max` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) can take a `key` argument to determine how to compare items.

So a simple `self.maxValNode = max(self.nodes, key=lambda node: node.val)` performs the same work (aside from your last line, which you'd leave as is). For slightly greater speed (and avoiding unnecessary `lambda`s, which are a pet peeve of mine), import the `operator` module beforehand, to allow:

```
from operator import attrgetter   # Top of file

self.maxValNode = max(self.nodes, key=attrgetter('val'))
```